# GPRBuild does not find gprconfig when called from the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ada, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnat

I have installed GNAT GPL 2017 on my Windows 10 system. Now I want to call the compiler from within a linux shell running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux. By adding the `bin` directory of my GNAT installation to the PATH, I got the following to work:

```
$ gnatmake.exe -P yaml.gpr
```

However, using GPRBuild does not work:

```
$ gprbuild.exe -P yaml.gpr
gprbuild: could not locate gprconfig for auto-configuration
```

I tried to call gprconfig from the command line and got this:

```
$ gprconfig.exe
No compilers found for target i686-pc-mingw32
```

It seems like gprbuild and gprconfig have problems with locating the GNAT binaries, while gnatmake is perfectly able to. How do I get gprbuild to work? Is there some environment variable I need to set?

Comment: I could build project using gprbuild on my Windows 10 / Ubuntu subsystem without any additional manipulations.  I have gnat bin directory in Windows PATH and it looks like the same PATH uses in linux subsystem. It looks like gprconfig search compilers in PATH. You may try  gprconfig.exe --mi-show-compilers to check if it found any of them.

Comment: @TimurSamkharadze The problem was fixed when I added the GNAT `bin` directory to the *Windows* PATH instead of just the linux shell's PATH. Would you post that as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could build project using gprbuild on my Windows 10 / Ubuntu subsystem without any additional manipulations. I have gnat bin directory in **Windows PATH** and it looks like the same PATH uses in linux subsystem. It looks like gprconfig search compilers in PATH. You may try gprconfig.exe --mi-show-compilers to check if it found any of them.

Kind regards